# Java SE 6 - Trouble recognizing directories with ZipEntry

Tags: java, zip, unzip

I've a problem unzipping files where directory are written without "/" at the end of the name.

The code works fine if the file content is:

```
BASEDIR/
BASEDIR/file1.txt
BASEDIR/file2.txt
```

When the central directory doesn't contain "/" at the end of its name, I got an error. In this case the content of the zip file is:

```
BASEDIR
BASEDIR/file1.txt
BASEDIR/file2.txt
```

Here the code I used to unzip the file

```
public static
void unzip(final String zipFilename, final String unzipDir)
        throws ZipException {

    ZipFile zipFile = null;
    try {
        final File directory = new File(unzipDir);
        // Check if the directory to extract to exists
        if(!directory.exists()) {
            // If not, create a new one.
            new File(unzipDir).mkdir();
        }

        final File checkFile = new File(zipFilename);
        if (checkFile.length() == 0) {
            throw new IOException("Empty file");
        }
        zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilename);
        Enumeration<?> e = zipFile.entries();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
            final ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)e.nextElement();
            final File destinationFile = new File(unzipDir,entry.getName());

            //create directories if required.
            destinationFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            //if the entry is directory, leave it. Otherwise extract it.
            if(entry.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                // Get the InputStream for current entry of the zip file using
                InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
                writeFile(is, fos);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new ZipException("error", ex);
    }
    finally {
        if(zipFile!=null) {
            try {
                zipFile.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new ZipException("error", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found the problem is the ZipEntry.isDirectory() method which works only if the name of the entry in the zip ends with "/" ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory%28%29 ), so it doesn't work in the second scenario. I'm not able to find a fix for this beaviour. How can I check if an entry is a directory without using isDirectory method? (Please note that I can not use third party library)

Comment: Are you using Java SE 6 or Java SE 7?

Comment: Java SE 6 (I read the Java SE 7 API and I found that the behavior is the same http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory%28%29 )

Comment: Consider to upgrade to Java SE 7, especially if you're using the Java implementation from Oracle as Oracle's Java SE 6 reached End of Life. Note the Java SE 7 introduced the new NIO.2 File API, which also makes it easier to work with Zip files (at least Oracle's Java SE 7): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html